# A Website in my Centos 6 server is picking incorrect PHP version

Tags: php, apache-2.4, centos6, php5

I have a CentOS 6 server that has PHP 5.6.20 installed:

```
# php -v
PHP 5.6.20 (cli) (built: Apr  2 2016 08:28:23)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

But when I run phpinfo() in a web site, it is reported PHP 5.6.13.

That version was installed before. How can I set apache to use always 5.6.20 version?

```
# httpd -V
Server version: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix)
Server built:   Nov  3 2015 13:24:41
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:47
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Compiled using: APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/opt/apache"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/opt/apache/bin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="logs/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

I have installed PHP 5.6.13 by compiling source. PHP 5.6.20 was installed by YUM.  How do I remove or make apache ignore 5.6.20?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I have not installed it. It was installed by hosting provider.

Comment: Then talk to your hosting provider.

Comment: Apparently, I have installed PHP 5.6.13 by compiling source. PHP 5.6.20 was installed by YUM. In such a case, hosting provider cannot help. That is why I posted the question here.

Comment: Blow it away and start over. It's not 100% possible to clean up a system which has had software manually compiled from source installed on it.

Comment: I know what happened. The problem is that the hosting provider uses a proprietary control panel that uses PHP version 5.6.13, however, I have installed PHP 5.6.20 using Yum. That Way, when I run php -v, I get version 5.6.20, but for websites, version 5.6.13 is recognized. So, Is there a way to point my websites to 5.6.20? if it isn't, how can I remove version 5.6.20 using Yum so that only 5.6.13 will be present?

Comment: See my previous comment, but start over _without_ the hosting provider's proprietary control panel.

Comment: by "start over" do you mean to recreate the server? or what is it more specifically?

Answer (score 0):

- to remove using `yum`: sudo yum remove php-5.6.20
- to use 5.6.13 (compiled from source) follow [PHP: Apache 2.x on Unix systems - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php)

I would *NOT* recommend using compiled version, as then you're introducing more maintenance for yourself (whenever new version comes out, you'd need to download and compile it again and again).

You may want to look into following instead, as at least it's RPM based and you'll get updates:

[PHP 5.6 on CentOS/RHEL 7.2 and 6.7 via Yum | Webtatic.com](https://webtatic.com/packages/php56/)

Comment: I have removed version 5.6.20, however, the website it is still thinking that it is 5.6.20... is there a ghost in my hosting? how can it be possible? and even, I have issued a "whereis php" and ran all executables that appear and they are all from different versions other than 5.6.20, so I don't know how this can be possible.

Comment: @jstuardo you forgot to restart `httpd`.

Comment: don't be so affirmative. Of course, I have restarted apache, even not only once, but several times. I have even restarted machine.